# Java "Get" and "Set" Methods

Tags: java, methods, get, set

I have two classes, in class `Player` i have the variable which is defined as `private int collectedDots` and I want to access in another class `Exit`.

I have defined the Get and Set method within class Player as such:

```
public void setCollectedDots(int cd)
{
    collectedDots = cd;
}

public int getCollectedDots()
{
    return collectedDots;
}
```

But now I want to access the `collectedDots` field from the `Exit` class. When I copy those two methods into the Exit class I keep getting the error `cannot find symbol - variable collectedDots`.

It was my understanding that I would then be able to retrieve the `collectedDots` variable from the Player class once I set the `get` and `set` methods..

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to call the methods on the Player in Exit, not copy them there.

Comment: @Pietu1998: you should probably make that an answer

Comment: @Pietu1998 I have tried doing that, I have an if statement that reads if (Player.getCollectedDots < 3) but it says I need to define the variable .setCollectedDots first, but I don't want to define it in the Exit class, I just want to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet that familiar with java but i guess you need to make sure that you have imported the other class that you would use or you can you an instance of a class:

collectedDots dots = new collectedDots();
int dotsValue = dots.getCollectedDots();

Answer (score -2):

You should use `public int collectedDots` variable rather than `private int collectedDots` variable